# Is it possible to resize the currently active partition, and how to do so?

Tags: debian, partition

I'm in a bind, as i forgot to resize the `/` mountpoint after removing the `/home` mountpoint during the installation of my dedicated server. To be honest, the installation GUI didn't explicitly told me that the partition was not going to be automatically resized, which is usually the default behavior. It is a remote server, and I cannot physically access it to plug a GParted live and just do it.

```
# lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 19.5G  0 part /
└─sda2   8:2    0  511M  0 part [SWAP]

# df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   14G  4.9G  74% /
```

There is almost 2TB of emptiness in between `sda1` & `sda2`.

The question is: Is there a way to increase the size of the primary&active partition, without booting live, and without unmounting said partition?

*I'm almost certain the answer is "nope, not possible" but I'd like confirmation, before doing a full re-installation.*

Comment: As said, remote server, so preferably CLI. I'll update the question for more clarity.

Comment: No server X installed yet on the remote server, and i'd prefer to keep it that way if possible. GParted does include a command line. But from what i remember, GParted need the partition to be unmounted to edit it, which is not an option here.

Comment: Welp... Well, if GUI GParted is able to resize mounted partitions, CLI parted should be able to to it too... Seems less risky than the second solution. Time to reread the man page

Comment: 'resize2fs' can do the trick on the fly at least on ext4 filesystem. I was using it with success few times, never on root partition though. So link proposed by Vlastimil Burian is a way to go. Still creating a backup would be a wise step to do.

Comment: Thankfully, the partition is small atm, backup will be fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses CLI commands to enlarge a *mounted* non-LVM partition containing `ext[234]` filesystem. For instance, the partition containing the system and to enlarge the filesystem within it.

This example expands `/dev/sda1` to be 30GiB in size. Be careful - only do this if current size < 30GiB and if there is room on the drive immediately above `sda1` for the proposed expansion!

First, this enlarges the partition and then, if that was successful, it enlarges the filesystem to use the new space:

```
parted /dev/sda resizepart 1 Y 30GiB && resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

To use this with an *unmounted* partition just leave out the `Y` (which is there to answer `parted`'s interactive question about modifying a mounted partition).

Comment: Does parted resizepart have an option to specify to use all available space? I can of course fetch the exact empty space, but i'd appreciate using an automated setting (if possible) to reduce potential problemes.

Comment: [Found my specific use-case in the doc.](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html#SEC30) Nope, cannot be automated.

Comment: @Lysarion, btw your linked doc info is for an old version of `parted` - the `resize` command was removed after 2.4. I'm using `parted` 3.2, this has `resizepart` command instead of `resize`. The [new manual info](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#resizepart) points out helpfully that if you want to shrink a partition you must shrink the filesystem on it first - not your use-case I realise.